# 'yield' enumerations that don't get 'finished' by caller - what happens

Tags: c#, yield-return

suppose I have

```
IEnumerable<string> Foo()
{
     try
     {

         /// open a network connection, start reading packets
         while(moredata)
         {
            yield return packet; 
        }
     }
     finally
      {
        // close connection 
      }
}
```

(Or maybe I did a 'using' - same thing). What happens if my caller goes

```
var packet = Foo().First();
```

I am just left with a leaked connection. When does the finally get invoked? Or does the right thing always happen by magic

**edit with answer and thoughts**

My sample and other 'normal' (foreach, ..) calling patterns will work nicely because they dispose of the IEnumerable (actually the IEnumerator returned by GetEnumerator). I must therefore have a caller somewhere thats doing something funky (explicitly getting an enumerator and not disposing it or the like). I will have them shot

**the bad code**

I found a caller doing

```
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = foo().GetEnumerator();
```

changed to

```
using(IEnumerator<T> enumerator = foo().GetEnumerator())
```

Comment: My best guess: returns only first `packet`(?)

Comment: @MaciejLos That doesn't answer the question he asked.

Comment: @Servy, i know. That was the reason i posted an comment. As you can see, i added `?` at the end of statement, becuase, i'm not sure. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> I am just left with a leaked connection.

No, you're not.

> When does the finally get invoked?

When the `IEnumerator<T>` is disposed, which `First` is going to do after getting the first item of the sequence (just like everyone should be doing when they use an `IEnumerator<T>`).

Now if someone wrote:

```
//note no `using` block on `iterator`
var iterator = Foo().GetEnumerator();
iterator.MoveNext();
var first = iterator.Current;
//note no disposal of iterator
```

*then* they would leak the resource, but there the bug is in the caller code, not the iterator block.

Comment: Makes sense. [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) states the same.

Answer (score 27):

You would not end up with leaked connection. Iterator objects produced by `yield return` are `IDisposable`, and LINQ functions are careful to ensure proper disposal.

For example, `First()` is implemented as follows:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null) {
        if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
    }
    else {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (e.MoveNext()) return e.Current;
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Note how the result of `source.GetEnumerator()` is wrapped in `using`. This ensures the call to `Dispose`, which in turn ensures the call of your code in the `finally` block.

Same goes for iterations by `foreach` loop: the code ensures disposal of the enumerator regardless of whether the enumeration completes or not.

The only case when you may end up with leaked connection is when you call `GetEnumerator` yourself, and fail to properly dispose of it. However, this is a mistake in the code using `IEnumerable`, not in the `IEnumerable` itself.

Answer (score 22):

Ok this question could use a little empirical data.

Using VS2015 and a scratch project, I wrote the following code:

```
private IEnumerable<string> Test()
{
    using (TestClass t = new TestClass())
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("1");
            yield return "1";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("2");
            yield return "2";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("3");
            yield return "3";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("4");
            yield return "4";
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Finally");
        }
    }
}

private class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Disposed");
    }
}
```

And then called it two ways:

```
foreach (string s in Test())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(s);
    if (s == "3") break;
}

string f = Test().First();
```

Which produces the following debug output

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
Finally
Disposed
1
Finally
Disposed
```

As we can see, it executes both the `finally` block and the `Dispose` method.

Comment: if in doubt write a test program :-) ty

Comment: @pm100 To add some more info: I specified that I was using the 2015 compiler, but I suspect that the scoping rules in the C# spec require this behavior. My suspicion is that terminating an enumerator implicitly acts like the last yield return was simply a return, and all the normal return rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special magic. If you check the doc on `IEnumerator<T>`, you'll find that it inherits from `IDisposable`. The `foreach` construct, as you know, is syntactic sugar which is decomposed by the compiler into a sequence of operations on an enumerator, and the whole thing is wrapped into a `try`/`finally` block, calling the `Dispose` on enumerator object.

When the compiler converts an iterator method (i. e. method containing `yield` statements) into an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerator<T>`, it handles the `try`/`finally` logic in the `Dispose` method of the generated class.

You might try to use ILDASM to analyze the code generated in your case. It's going to be pretty complex but it'll give you the idea.